# Thesaurus File support in SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, full-text-search

I am trying to implement full text search (Thesaurus Files feature) on SQL Azure database. I am not able to locate the thesaurus file in Azure SQL database. Is it supported in SQL Azure DB? The following document says it is supported.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017

But I am unable to locate the file and using following command-

```
EXEC sys.sp_fulltext_load_the`enter code here`saurus_file 1033
```

Getting following error:

> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1
>   Could not find stored procedure 'sys.sp_fulltext_load_thesaurus_file'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure SQL database support full text search. You have got it from the document you find. You also can reference this doucment [Full-Text Search is now available in Azure SQL Database (GA)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/full-text-search-is-now-available-for-preview-in-azure-sql-database/).

Note:

> Full-Text Search is an optional component of the SQL Server Database Engine. If you didn't select Full-Text Search when you installed SQL Server, run SQL Server Setup again to add it.

Please make sure you have select the Full-Text Search component.

But Azure SQL database doesn't support '[sp_fulltext_load_thesaurus_file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-fulltext-load-thesaurus-file-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)'.
[image]

And Azure SQL database also doesn't support you [Configure and Manage Thesaurus Files for Full-Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/configure-and-manage-thesaurus-files-for-full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017):
[image]

Hope this helps.